# Filtering in Django Dynamic REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

How can I filter in django dynamic REST (https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest) with `OR` clause?

I need to implement queryset like

```
User.objects.filter(Q(username="admin") | Q(first_name="test"))
```

Is it possible to do it via request GET query parameters - something like `api/users?filter{username}=admin <OR> filter{first_name}=test`?

Comment: Looking at the source code of [DynamicFilter](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest/blob/master/dynamic_rest/filters.py#L153-L176) I don’t think that’s possible.